# Which SSIS transform can I use to join and update table?

Tags: ssis

I have a data flow task in which I am reading data from sql server table A (id, order_no, amount).

I want to join this result to table B (order_no, amount) located on another sql server, ON tableA.order_no = table B.order_no and perform a addition of the both amounts and store it back into table B.

I have connection manager setup for both sql server databases.

Which transform can I use to perform this operation?

Comment: If you are going back and forth between different servers the best way is to create staging tables on the 2nd server.  Send the data to that stage table, get the data you need by doing update on that stage table, then pull the data back from the stage table into your main table and do your update with the data pulled from other server.  I do this all the time and it works for small or large data sets.  If you try to do it in the data flow all the data will need to be in memory and if the data set is large ,this could cause issues.

Comment: So i will do all this in 1 execute sql task?

Comment: No you would need 3 data flow tasks.  1.  To send list of records you want from the other server, 2.  Do work to get extra data on 2nd server, 3.  Pull data back from 2nd server to original.  I will try to create a flow to show it better.

Answer (score 0):

This dtsx design may help:

- Create a temp table on server B temp db via Execute SQL Task.
- Create a temp table and load table A data into via a Data Flow Task.
- Create another Execute SQL Task to join table B to the newly
  created temp table on order_no and make a tableB.amount +
  temptable.amount as [Added Amounts] column.

You did not specify if the new column will be needed in table B or you will need to update table B's amounts. Pending this the code will be adjusted.

This process overall will eliminate db overhead.